# Code generator for expressions using Sethi-Ullman algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, parsing, compiler-construction, code-generation

Give a [AST tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), I want to generate an assembly-like language. I'm trying using [Sethi-Ullman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sethi%E2%80%93Ullman_algorithm) algorithm but I have some questions in the algorithm implemetation.

#### What should I do when I run out of registers?

currently I do the following:

Emit a `push REG` where `REG` is the register of right subtree, evaluate left subtree, get one free register assign as register of right subtree and then emit a `POP REG` operation where `REG` is the register of right subtree too.

#### How should I implement the function to get a free register? currently I'm using an implementation like this instead of a stack-based:

```
enum Reg { Reg_r0, Reg_r1 };
Reg regs[] = { Reg_r0, Reg_r1 };
    Reg getreg() {
             static int c;
        if(c == sizeof(regs) / sizeof(int))
        c = 0;
        return regs[c++];
    }
```

Here's a pseudo-code (from C-language) how to implement it from what I unsertood(including the `label()` function)

```
// K is the number of registers available
int K = 2;
void gen(AST ast) {
    if(ast.left != null && ast.right != null) {
        int l = ast.left.n;
        int r = ast.right.n;
        
        if(l >= K && r >= K) {
            gen(ast.right);
            ast.n -= 1;
            emit_operation(PUSH, ast.right.reg);
            gen(ast.left);
            ast.reg = getreg();
            emit_operation(POP, ast.right.reg);
        } else if(l >= r) {
            gen(ast.left);
            gen(ast.right);
            ast.n -= 1;
        } else if(l < r) {
            gen(ast.right);
            gen(ast.left);
            ast.n -= 1;
        }
        
        ast.reg = getreg();
        Reg r1 = ast.left.reg;
        Reg r2 = ast.right.reg;
        emit_operation(ast.type, r1, r2);
    } else if(ast.type == Type_id || ast.type == Type_number) {
        ast.n += 1;
        ast.reg = getreg();
        emit_load(ast);
    } else {
        print("gen() error");
        // error
    }
}

// ershov numbers
void label(AST ast) {
    if(ast == null)
        return;
    
    label(ast.left);
    label(ast.right);
    
    if(ast.type == Type_id || ast.type == Type_number)
        ast.n = 1;
    // ast has two childrens
    else if(ast.left not null && ast.right not null) {      
        int l = ast.left.n;
        int r = ast.right.n;
        
        if(l == r)
            ast.n = 1 + l;
        else
            ast.n = max(1, l, r);
    }
    // ast has one child
    else if(ast.left not null && ast.right is null)
        ast.n = ast.left.n;
    else
        print("label() error!");
}
```

**EDIT:** Tell me please if more context is needed to understand this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sethi-Ullman is really just a scheduling algorithm, not a register allocation algorithm, so it just tells you the *order* in which to do operations to minimize the number of registers needed; it does not tell you *which* registers to use where.

So you need to combine it with a register allocation strategy -- usually just a greedy allocator.  Then there's the question of what to do if you run out of registers -- do you insert spills inline, or abort and do something else?

In order to do simple greedy allocation inline with your scheduling and instruction generation (what you seem to be doing with your simple `gen` recursive procedure), you'll need to keep track of which registers are in use at any given time.  The easiest way is by adding an extra `in_use` argument to your gen function:

```
typedef unsigned RegSet; /* using a simple bitmask for a set -- assuming that
                          * unsigned is big enough to have a bit per register */

void gen(AST *ast, RegSet in_use) {
    if(ast->left != 0 && ast->right != 0) {
        if (ast->left->n >= ast->right->n) {
            gen(ast->left, in_use);
            gen(ast->right, in_use | (1 << ast->left->reg));
        } else {
            gen(ast->right, in_use);
            gen(ast->left, in_use | (1 << ast->right->reg)); }
        ast->reg = ast->left->reg
        emit_operation(ast->type, ast->left->reg, ast->right->reg);
    } else if(ast->type == Type_id || ast->type == Type_number) {
        ast->reg = pick_unused_register(in_use);
        emit_load(ast);
    } else ....
```

Note that you need a separate recursive pass to calculate `n` for each node (Sethi-Ullman inherently requires two traversals, with the first traversal computing bottom up the `n` value for the second traversal to use top-down).

Now the above code doesn't deal with running out of registers at all.  To do that, you need to insert some spills.  One way is to detect that all registers are in use before making a recursive call and spill then, restoring afterwards:

```
void gen(AST *ast, RegSet in_use) {
    if(ast->left != 0 && ast->right != 0) {
        Reg spill = NoRegister; /* no spill yet */
        AST *do1st, *do2nd;     /* what order to generate children */
        if (ast->left->n >= ast->right->n) {
            do1st = ast->left;
            do2nd = ast->right;
        } else {
            do1st = ast->right;
            do2nd = ast->left; }
        gen(do1st, in_use);
        in_use |= 1 << do1st->reg;
        if (all_used(in_use)) {
            spill = pick_register_other_than(do1st->reg);
            in_use &= ~(1 << spill);
            emit_operation(PUSH, spill); }
        gen(do2nd, in_use);
        ast->reg = ast->left->reg
        emit_operation(ast->type, ast->left->reg, ast->right->reg);
        if (spill != NoRegister)
            emit_operation(POP, spill);
    } else ...
```

Of course, this turns out to be not terribly efficient -- its usually better to spill sooner and refill later, but only when you know you're going to run out of registers.

Comment: You don't seem to need `Reg l, r` or `return l`, since the function has return type `void` and you never set `l` or use `r`.

Comment: @rici: Leftovers from before I realized that the OP is storing the registers allocated in the AST.  An alternative implementation would have `gen` return the register allocated for the result and not need the `reg` field in `ast`.

Comment: Thanks very much! helped a lot! So `label()` do same job as `SethiUllman()` function? I was confusing because from where I get this it was named something like "register allocation for trees"... and I assumed `label()` to set `n` and `SethiUllman()` to generate the code. I will remove `reg` member and return in `gen()` function instead of as you mentioned.

Comment: I have another question I can't figure it out myself: how do I make sure to resulting expression value be always in same register? no matter how complex is the AST. I mean, to a tree from expression `2 + (2 + 2)` the result is in `R1` and not `R0`. The assembly-like code from this is something like this:  LOAD R0,2
`        LOAD R1,2
        ADD R0,R1
        LOAD R1,2
        ADD R1,R0
`

Comment: The code above assumes the destination of a binary op is the same register as the left operand (thus the `ast->reg = ast->left-reg` assignment).  So while the final result ends up in R1, its labelled as being in R1.

Comment: The code above is right. However, final result might be labelled as begin in R0 but actual is in R0. I wanted to swap it but it's topic for another thread. Thanks again. It helped a lot.

Comment: If you want gen to have the result end up in a particular register, you could add another argument to it (dest register) and arrange your register choices so that works out.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Shouldn't be `ast->reg = do1st->reg` instead of `ast->reg = ast->left->reg` ?

Comment: No -- I'm assuming you are generating code for a CPU where the dest and left src must be the same register (such as x86, or just about any 2-register ISA, rather than a 3-register ISA)