# Code generation for expressions with fixed/preassigned register

Tags: c, algorithm, compiler-construction, code-generation, compiler-theory

I'm using this (see below) algorithm(take idea from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618268/code-generator-for-expressions-using-sethi-ullman-algorithm) answer) to code generation from a tree. I'm targeting x86 arch, now I need to deal with mul/div instructions which uses registers eax/ebx as argument.

My question is:

How do I modify this to load operands of a certain instruction to load at fixed register? say, for `mul` instruction load left and right subtree on `eax` and `ebx` registers. My current implementation is: pass current node begin evaluated as argument and if it's `MUL` or `DIV` set `reg` to `R0` or `R1` according to tree's side, if it's `LEFT` or `RIGHT` respectively. If `reg` is `in_use`, push `reg` on stack and mark it as begin free(not implmented yet). The current implementation doesn't work because it does assert in `assert(r1 != r2)` in `emit_load()` function (meaning both registers passed as argument are equals like `r1 = REG_R0` and `r2 = REG_R0`)

```
      void gen(AST *ast, RegSet in_use, AST *root) {
            if(ast->left != 0 && ast->right != 0) {
                Reg spill = NoRegister; /* no spill yet */
                AST *do1st, *do2nd;     /* what order to generate children */
                if (ast->left->n >= ast->right->n) {
                    do1st = ast->left;
                    do2nd = ast->right;
                } else {
                    do1st = ast->right;
                    do2nd = ast->left; }
                gen(do1st, in_use);
                in_use |= 1 << do1st->reg;
                if (all_used(in_use)) {
                    spill = pick_register_other_than(do1st->reg);
                    in_use &= ~(1 << spill);
                    emit_operation(PUSH, spill); 
                }
                gen(do2nd, in_use);
                ast->reg = ast->left->reg
                emit_operation(ast->type, ast->left->reg, ast->right->reg);
                if (spill != NoRegister)
                    emit_operation(POP, spill);
            } else if(ast.type == Type_id || ast.type == Type_number) {
                if(node->type == MUL || node->type == DIV) {
                    REG reg;
                    if(node_side == ASTSIDE_LEFT)  reg = REG_R0; 
                    if(node_side == ASTSIDE_RIGHT) reg = REG_R1;
                    if(is_reg_in_use(in_use, reg)) {
                        emit_operation(PUSH, reg);
                    }

                } else {
                  ast->reg = pick_unused_register(in_use);
                  emit_load(ast);
             }
            } else {
                print("gen() error");
                // error
            }
    }

// ershov numbers
void label(AST ast) {
    if(ast == null)
        return;

    label(ast.left);
    label(ast.right);

    if(ast.type == Type_id || ast.type == Type_number)
        ast.n = 1;
    // ast has two childrens
    else if(ast.left not null && ast.right not null) {      
        int l = ast.left.n;
        int r = ast.right.n;

        if(l == r)
            ast.n = 1 + l;
        else
            ast.n = max(1, l, r);
    }
    // ast has one child
    else if(ast.left not null && ast.right is null)
        ast.n = ast.left.n;
    else
        print("label() error!");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a one-pass code generator like this, your options are limited.  It's probably simpler to generate 3-address code or some other linear intermediate representation first and *then* worry about register targeting (this is the name for what you're trying to accomplish).

Nonetheless, what you want to do is possible.  The caveat is that you won't get very high quality code. To make it better, you'll have to throw away this generator and start over.

The main problem you're experiencing is that Sethi-Ulman labeling is not a code generation algorithm.  It's just a way of choosing the *order* of code generation.  You're still missing important ideas.

With all that out of the way, some points:

Pushing and popping registers to save them temporarily makes life difficult. The reason is pretty obvious.  You can only get access to the saved values in LIFO order.

Things become easier if you allocate "places" that may be either registers or memory locations in the stack frame.  The memory locations effectively extend the register file to make it as large as necessary.  A slight complication is that you'll need to remember for each function how many words are required for places in that function's stack frame and backpatch the function preamble to allocate that number.

Next, implement a global operand stack where each stack element is a PLACE.  A PLACE is a descriptor telling where an operand that has been computed by already-emitted code is located: register or memory and how to access it.  (For better code, you can also allow a PLACE to be a user variable and/or immediate value, but such PLACEs are never returned by the PLACE allocator described below.  Additionally, the more kinds of PLACEs you allow, the more cases must be handled by the code emitter, also described below.)

The general principle is "be lazy."  The later we can wait to emit code, the more information will be available.  With more information, it's possible to generate better code.  The stack of PLACEs does a reasonably good job of accomplishing this.

The code generator invariant is that it emits code that leaves the result PLACE at the top of the operand stack.

You will also need a PLACE allocator.  This keeps track of registers and the memory words in use.  It allocates new memory words if all registers and current words are already busy.

Registers in the PLACE allocator can have three possible statuses:  FREE, BUSY, PINNED.  A PINNED register is one needed to hold a value that can't be moved.  (We'll use this for instructions with specific register requirements.)   A BUSY register is one needed for a value that's okay to be moved to a different PLACE as required. A FREE register holds no value.

Memory in the PLACE allocator is either FREE or BUSY.

The PLACE allocator needs at least these entry points:

1. `allocate_register` pick a FREE register R, make it BUSY, and return R.  If no FREE registers are available, allocate a FREE memory word P, move a BUSY register R's contents there, and return R.
2. `pin_register(R)` does as follows:  If R is PINNED, raise a fatal error.  If R is BUSY, get a FREE PLACE P (either register or memory word), emit code that moves the contents of R to P, mark R PINNED and return.  If R is FREE, just mark it PINNED and return.

Note that when pinning or allocating register R requires moving its contents, the allocator must update the corresponding element in the operand stack. What was R must be changed to P.  For this purpose, the allocator maintains a map taking each register to the operand stack PLACE that describes it.

With all this complete, the code generator for binary ops will be simple:

```
gen_code_for(ast_node) {
  if (ast_node->left_first) {
    gen_code_for(ast_node->left_operand)
    gen_code_for(ast_node->right_operand)
  } else {
    gen_code_for(ast_node->right_operand)
    gen_code_for(ast_node->left_operand)
    swap_stack_top_2()  // get stack top 2 elements in correct order
  }
  emit_code_for(ast_node)
}
```

The code emitter will work like this:

```
emit_code_for(ast_node) {
  switch (ast_node->kind) {
    case DIV:  // An operation that needs specific registers
      pin_register(EAX) // Might generate some code to make EAX available
      pin_register(EDX) // Might generate some code to make EDX available
      emit_instruction(XOR, EDX, EDX) // clear EDX
      emit_instruction(MOV, EAX, stack(1)) // lhs to EAX
      emit_instruction(DIV, stack(0)) // divide by rhs operand
      pop(2) // remove 2 elements and free their PLACES
      free_place(EDX) // EDX not needed any more.
      mark_busy(EAX)  // EAX now only busy, not pinned.
      push(EAX) // Push result on operand stack
      break;
    case ADD: // An operation that needs no specific register.
      PLACE result = emit_instruction(ADD, stack(1), stack(0))
      pop(2)
      push(result)
      break;
    ... and so on
  }
}
```

Finally, the instruction emitter must know what to do when its operands have combinations of types not supported by the processor instruction set.  For example, it might have to load a memory PLACE into a register.

```
emit_instruction(op, lhs, [optional] rhs) {
  switch (op) {
    case DIV:
      assert(RAX->state == PINNED && RDX->state == PINNED)
      print_instruction(DIV, lhs)
      return RAX;
    case ADD:
      if (lhs->kind == REGISTER) {
        print_instruction(ADD, lhs, rhs)
        return lhs
      }
      if (rhs->kind == REGISTER) {
        print_instruction(ADD, rhs, lhs)
        return rhs
      }
      // Both operands are MEMORY
      R = allocate_register // Get a register; might emit some code.
      print_instruction(MOV, R, lhs)
      print_instruction(ADD, R, rhs) 
      return R
      ... and so on ...
```

I've necessarily let out many details.  Ask what isn't clear.

**OP's Questions Addressed**

You're right that I intended `stack(n)` to be the PLACE that is `n` from the top of the operand stack.

Leaves of the syntax tree just push a PLACE for a computed value on the operand stack to satisfy the invariant.

As I said above, you can either create special kinds of PLACEs for these operands (user-labeled memory locations and/or immediate values), or - simpler and as you proposed - allocate a register and emit code that loads the value into that register, then push the register's PLACE onto the stack.  The simpler method will result in unnecessary load instructions and consume more registers than needed.  For example `x = x + 1` will generate code something like:

```
mov esi, [ebp + x]
mov edi, 1
add esi, edi
mov [ebp + x], esi
```

Here I'm using `x` to denote the base pointer offset of the variable.

With PLACEs for variables and literals, you can easily get:

```
mov esi, [ebp + x]
add esi, 1
mov [ebp + x], esi
```

By making the code generator aware of the PLACE where the assignment needs to put its answer, you can get

```
add [ebp + x], 1
```

or equivalently

```
inc [bp + x]
```

Accomplish this by adding a parameter `PLACE *target` to the code generator that describes where the final value of the computed expression value needs to go.  If you're not currently compiling an expression, this is set to NULL.  Note that with `target`, the code generator invariant changes: The expression result's PLACE is at the top of the operand stack *unless* `target` is set.  In that case, it's already been computed into the target's PLACE.

How would this work on `x = x + 1`?  The `ASSIGNMENT` case in the `emit_code_for` procedure would provide the `target` as the PLACE for `x` when it calls itself recursively to compile `x + 1`.  This delegates responsibility downward for getting the computed value to the right memory location, which is `x`.  The `emit_code_for` case for `ADD` ow calls `emit_code_for` recursively to evaluate the operands `x` and `1` onto the stack.  Since we have PLACEs for user variables and immediate values, these are pushed on the stack while generating no code at all. The `ADD` emitter must now be smart enough to know that if it sees a memory location L and a literal constant C on the stack and the target is also L, then it can emit `add L, C`, and it's done.

Remember that every time you make the code generator "smarter" by providing it with more information to make its decisions like this, it will become longer and more complicated because there are more cases to handle.

Comment: First of all, thank you ver much! first I accepted your answer because it's what I'm looking for and bounty is ending. When I back home I will read it carefully and give you my feedback and my questions.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I removed my last two comments. I didn't see you had already answered. I removed because I had solved this using the follwoing approach: a new tmember in enum Kind called 'node' and then modified print_instruction() to deal with Place of this kind. So, stack(n) might return a register,memory (value to put on stack) and a node. Place of Kind.node  means it's either a constant number or a identifier(not implemented yet). A new member in the struct Place has beed added and hold if kind = node, the index of this node in the node stack table.

Comment: Valeus gets pushed on snode tack table by emit_code_for() if type is either number of identifier. Something like this:`case Type_number:
                int i = push_node(node);
                Place p = new Place();
                          p.kind = Kind.node; p.nodeoffset = i;
                push(p);`

                break;`

Comment: @TheMask I guess this can work. But it's likely to lead to tricky code.  A memory location is an l-value.  A literal is an r-value.  This difference means that they're really two distinctly different kinds of PLACEs.  Using a single kind of PLACE for both (what you are calling node) isn't a very clean design, even though it may work okay.  You can actually use the same kind of PLACE that you use for temporaries in memory to also hold user variables: Kind.MEMORY. A stack frame offset covers both cases.  So you only need one additional, the literal constant.

Comment: It's really a bad design. I'm facing a problem now: I can't determine the last register used if it's of node. I haven't handled Kind.memory yet. But if one identifier(variable) is seen, print_instruction() see it's of node type and then call print_node() which see a Type_id node and then print its name enclosed [ and ]. As I've said, I haven't handled identifiers yet and then nor stack. First I want to make a version with constants working and then implemente variables. Should I handle differently? my emit_instruction() doesn't differ much from the one you described.

Comment: Actually, I have two stacks for the nodes and places, respectively. I made a change in PLACE to it hold a new kind, the node. This hold the node's offset in the stack of nodes. Aren't really mixed into a single stack.  stack(N) does manage PLACE only. But I feel it isn't what you said to I do... but I don't know how...

Comment: This is my last question: I don't handle nonbinary operators in gen_code_for() and call it recusively if there's non-null left and right sides but emit_code_for() is called anyway. Is this right?

Comment: Update: I solved problem to determine last register used. Actually, I change a bit the designer and I don't need this anymore. But I made assumption now I want to know if it's Always true(Although it might be obvious for you). I'm getting moves like MOV EAX, EAX and MOV EBX, EBX with div operation and I want to make sure
the follwing code is a real fix for this and willn't break anything on the code generation. http://pastebin.com/4S4tuE2u

Comment: Well, sure, it's useless to emit a move from any place to itself, so you should just skip.  The `print_instruction` routine in my code can take care of that.  Your if statements can do that as well.

Comment: I thought actually it's a was bug

Comment: Could I give you more 50? :)

Comment: In your code, you do have two stacks: one of registers and another to places, right?

Comment: No.  A place can be a register, a memory location (which is either a temporary allocated by the compiler to hold a sub-expression value or a user-defined variable or parameter), or a literal value.  When the emitter looks at the top two stack positions (and the target operand if you're using that), it must be able to handle all the possible pairwise combinations - up to 3 (or 6 with the target) for each op. There is only one stack. If you were making an interpreter, the stack would hold the values themselves. In the code generator, it contains a description of where the value has been stored.

Comment: (I'm sorry for my bad english; not my native language speaker)

Comment: Shouldn't a pinned register be pushed on opstack too?

Comment: Not automatically. For a 32 bit DIV, you pin eax and edx in order to ensure they're available as the result target, but only push eax after code is  emitted because that's where the answer is.  Pinning is just a form of allocation where we force the particular register we want.

Comment: Check out the assembly output: http://pastebin.com/dEwwEaw5 and how I'm dealing with it: http://pastebin.com/Xn4Pg7PG I put comments to try make clean as possible what I'm trying. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @TheMask Looks like it's coming along pretty well.  Congratulations.

Comment: In the of the code generation I should end up with zero values on stack, right?

Comment: The generator invariant is that places of sub-expression values are stored are on the stack. Depending on the language you're generating code for, this means zero are left at the end if all values have been assigned in a statement and the statement has a `void` type.  In a language like C where statements can have values, you'll generally end with one place on the stack after processing the last one (because its value is available but has not been used), which you can pop manually before terminating.

Comment: Thanks. I understood why I've Always one value left on the end of code generation. I didn't still make it working 100%. When I fix one error I make another. It's really hard. :\ Check out it this if you can help me http://pastebin.com/fn9pfvwx

Comment: I feel I'm requesting you too much. But very hardly I will find some other place/someone to get help like this.

Comment: Something I'm missing on this explanation: when/how did the values get on the operando stack? say, I have tree from expression `2+x` and deal with the operator  `+` on `emit_code_for()` but where did I deal with the left and right value of that operator? i.e, where/in which function did `2` and `x` pushed on the operando stack so that I get them by `stack(0)` and `stack(1)` on `emit_code_for()` function? I know you have answered it more than one year ago but I hope you're still around and can answer. Thanks

Comment: The case for AST node(2) pushes a PLACE of type immediate. For x it pushes a PLACE that's a reference to the location where x is stored (frame pointer offset or absolute address if x is static). For +, emit_code always deals with the top two stack positions. Here it sees that it must add an immediate and a stack reference and chooses the best instruction(s) for this purpose. For x86, it would load the value of x into a register in one instruction and then add the immediate value to the register. It would pop the args from the stack and push a PLACE for the register. @Jack

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I added a type member to place struct to I know if it's a immediate value/memory address/register. All the immediate values gets pushed on operand stack before the operators are proccessed.